# RailsのActionController::BaseのBaseクラスはどこに存在する？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsプロジェクトの中にapplication_contorller.rbと言うファイルがあるかと思います。

その上で、ApplicationContorollerクラスが、ActionController::Baseクラスを継承していることはわかりましたが、ActionController::Baseクラスはどこにあるのでしょうか？

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> https://api.rubyonrails.org/

上記ページは、 rails の公式 api ドキュメントページで、 `ActionController` に限らず、 rails のクラスやメソッドについて調べたい場合は、ここから検索すると良いです。

`ActionController::Base` については、以下が本体の様子です。

- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb